# I want to render a partial on click in typo3

Tags: typo3, fluid

Here is my code

```
<f:for each="{websites}" as="website" iteration="i">
<tr class="tx_goclientwebsites__row">
    <td>{i.index+1}</td>
    <td>{website.name}</td>
    <td>{website.url}</td>
    <td id="renderBusinessDisconnected">{website.locationsCount}</td>
    <td>
        <span
            class="rounded-circle icon_circle cursor-pointer"
            data-toggle="tooltip"
            onclick="copyToClipboard('{website.apiKey}')"
            title="{f:translate(key: 'copyTooltip')}"
            data-placement="top"
        >
            <i id="copyid" class="img-icon">
                <f:image
                    src="EXT:go_clientwebsites/Resources/Public/Icons/copy.svg"
                    alt="CopyId"
                    class="copyicon"
                />
            </i>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

</f:for>

Here is the partial

```
<f:render partial="BusinessDisconnected" arguments="{website}" />
```

Now I want to render this partial whenever the user clicks on `<td id="renderBusinessDisconnected">` and pass the website of that iteration as an argument to the partial.
Can anyone help me with this? **Thank you in advance :)**

Answer (score 3):

fluid is always rendered Serverside. there a generally two aproaches to have content be shown on click.

1. render everything an hide via css "display:none" and then use javascript to show this. for most parts this is the easiest solution. and i would prefer it when the content is "static" so it will not change on frontend setting.
2. is the "AJAX" aproach where you dynamicallly load the needed content from the server. this is usally more complex as you need to setup some kind of rendering to only render the part you are requesting. this can be archived in serveral ways:

- setting up a PageType which only renders your partial
- add a plugin Action to render the Partial (using the PropagateResponseException)
- adding an middleware to have some kind of API endpoint.
- using the typoscirpt-rendering extension which allows to render typoscript paths out of bound.

regardeless of the way the server renders the content. you need then javascript to fetch the result url which also can add to complexity due to asyncron javascript fetching, handeling network erros, showing spinners. etc.
making shure your solution works in harmony with your typo3 routing.

as the second aproach has way more complexety i would avoid it if its not stricly nessessary. because usually delivering some "small" html chunk with the first request to show them on demand is way easier.